# How to make requests to Payara Micro using API?

Tags: payara, payara-micro

I am trying to complete a test case that deploys a war and makes some REST requests.

I want to use Payara Micro JAVA API and I've had a good start with setting up a boostrap

```
bootStrap = PayaraMicro.getInstance().setHttpPort(6060).bootStrap();
```

... and deploying my war

```
bootStrap.deploy(new File("{path}"));
```

My war deploys correctly.

Where do I go from here? Where do I point my requests to?

Comment: By default Payara Micro listens on port 8080

Answer (score 0):

The context path is the same as the name of the WAR you've deployed. ([See example cURL in this README](https://github.com/payara/Payara-Examples/blob/master/rest-examples%2Frest-jcache%2FREADME.md))

So if you are deploying `my-war.war` with your settings above, then you would go to:

```
http://127.0.0.1:6060/my-war
```

Answer (score 0):

OK so I was able to setup up a standard javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget and Client and make regular requests after all.

It's nice to be able to design system test in JUnit. Payara rocks ;)